# How to strip string of all integers and spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.3

I want to know how to strip an input of all integers and spaces. I know the `.strip()` function in Python can do this, but it only works for characters at the beginning/end of the string.

Here is my code:

```
    battery = input("Is the phone charger turned on at the plug?").lower()
        if battery == "y" or battery == "yes":
            print("Replace the phone's battery or contact the phone's manufacturer.")
            break
```

So if the user inputs 'ye2s', the program will get rid of the '2' and take it as 'yes'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like follows using `isdigit()` string method:

```
battery = ''.join(c for c in battery if not c.isdigit() and not c.isspace())
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have needed :))

Comment: @mvelay You forgot removing spaces.

Comment: `c.isdigit()` may match too much (it may allow things that `int()` won't accept). Use `c.isdecimal()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `translate`. The last argument to `str.maketrans` are the characters to delete:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans("", "", "0123456789 ")
>>> "ye2s with spac3es".translate(table)
'yeswithspaces'
```

It is likely to be faster than manipulating the string as list.

### Dealing with all unicode decimal chars

As [J.F.Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) noted, unicode provides many
more characters being considered decimal digits.

All digits:

```
>>> len("".join(c for c in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1)) if c.isdecimal()))
460
```

So to remove all possible decimal (and space) chars:

```
>>> delchars = "".join(c for c in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1)) if c.isdecimal() or c.isspace())
>>> table = str.maketrans("", "", delchars)
>>> "ye2s with spac3es".translate(table)
'yeswithspaces'
```

Comment: you could use `"".join(c for c in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1)) if c.isdecimal() or c.isspace())` instead of `"0123456789 "`. OP should use the opposite strategy (though it would be a different question): use a whitelist instead of the blacklist.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 87 chars long joke using Python.

Comment: do you understand that there are non-ascii digits?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Now I understand. There are really 450 other characters being digits which I did not delete. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) to do the job, note `\d` means any digit `\s` means any space:

```
>>> import re
>>> input = 'ye255 s'
>>> re.sub('[\d\s]+', '', 'ye255 s')
'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

All good answers, nothing wrong with whatever method you choose.
My answer is to use `.lower()` so your program will be recognising `"Y"` `"Yes"` `"YEs"` and `"YES"`

change this line:

```
if battery == "y" or battery == "yes":
```

to this line:

```
if battery.lower() == "y" or battery.lower() == "yes":
```

or alternatively, if you only like to use `.lower()` once, you can do this

```
if battery.lower() in ["y", "yes"]:
```

HTH.